# Getting syntax error when using shorthand if/else code

Tags: php, syntax-error, shorthand-if

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the below shorthand if/else code?

```
<div class="holder <?php echo (!empty($bid_info['sale_price'] ? 'holder7' : 'holder4'); ?>">
```

According to [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) it seems right!?

Though I am getting the below error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ')' in ...........
```

Comment: It looks as though you're missing a parenthesis after `$bid_info['sale_price']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing ) before the ?

```
 <?php echo (!empty($bid_info['sale_price']) ? 'holder7' : 'holder4'); ?>
```

Comment: The parentheses is at the end of the statement. I initially had it there and it wasn't working, so I looked at the example under `Conditional Welcome Message` on that page and he didn't have one so I removed it.

Comment: nvm.... I see it now, it's for the empty function. My bad.

Comment: @Brett Count them, add 1 for a ( and subtract 1 for a ) if you dont get the answer 0 you have to many or not enough.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, as per my comment above I overlooked the one for the empty function.